# How to combine Tic Tac Toe function "Chose function" in one function and to select cell instead of hidden?

Tags: javascript, html-table, tic-tac-toe

I'm new to the JavaScript world and I was hoping that you  would help me on the basic level of coding.

How to make my Tic-Tac-Toe (X and O Choices) only in one function?
I also would like to select the cell instead of the hidden button.

I tried with respect to the main function:

```
    if (document.getElementById("cell1").checked = true)
    if (document.getElementById("cell1").onclick= click)
```

but didn't work.

This is the function I am trying to accomplish my tic-tac-toe with

```
  var nextTurn = 'X'
  function chose1() {
    if (document.getElementById("Hidden1").checked = true) {
        if (document.getElementById('cell1').innerText == "") {
            document.getElementById('cell1').innerText = nextTurn;
            changeTurn();
        }
    }


    else if (document.getElementById("Hidden2").checked = true) {
        if (document.getElementById('cell2').innerText == "") {
            document.getElementById('cell2').innerText = nextTurn;
            changeTurn();
        }
    }


    else if (document.getElementById("Hidden3").checked = true) {
        if (document.getElementById('cell3').innerText == "") {
            document.getElementById('cell3').innerText = nextTurn;
            changeTurn();
        }
    }


    else if (document.getElementById("Hidden4").checked = true) {
        if (document.getElementById('cell4').innerText == "") {
            document.getElementById('cell4').innerText = nextTurn;
            changeTurn();
        }
    }


    else if (document.getElementById("Hidden5").checked = true) {
        if (document.getElementById('cell5').innerText == "") {
            document.getElementById('cell5').innerText = nextTurn;
            changeTurn();
        }
    }


    else if (document.getElementById("Hidden6").checked = true) {
        if (document.getElementById('cell6').innerText == "") {
            document.getElementById('cell6').innerText = nextTurn;
            changeTurn();
        }
    }


    else if (document.getElementById("Hidden7").checked = true) {
        if (document.getElementById('cell7').innerText == "") {
            document.getElementById('cell7').innerText = nextTurn;
            changeTurn();
        }
    }


    else if (document.getElementById("Hidden8").checked = true) {
        if (document.getElementById('cell8').innerText == "") {
            document.getElementById('cell8').innerText = nextTurn;
            changeTurn();
        }
    }


    else if (document.getElementById("Hidden9").checked = true) {
        if (document.getElementById('cell9').innerText == "") {
            document.getElementById('cell9').innerText = nextTurn;
            changeTurn();
        }
    }
 }

 function changeTurn() {
    if (nextTurn == 'X') {
        nextTurn = 'O';
    } else {
        nextTurn = 'X';
    }
 }
```

These are the tables that I am calling the function with.

```
 <table border="10" cellpadding="40">
 <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td id="cell1" onclick="chose1()">
        </td>
            <input id="Hidden1" type="hidden" />
        <td id="cell2" onclick="chose2()">
            <input id="Hidden2" type="hidden" />
        </td>
        <td id="cell3" onclick="chose3()">
            <input id="Hidden3" type="hidden" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="cell4" onclick="chose4()">
            <input id="Hidden4" type="hidden" />
        </td>
        <td id="cell5" onclick="chose5()">
            <input id="Hidden5" type="hidden" />
        </td>
        <td id="cell6" onclick="chose6()">
            <input id="Hidden6" type="hidden" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="cell7" onclick="chose7()">
            <input id="Hidden7" type="hidden" />
        </td>
        <td id="cell8" onclick="chose8()">
            <input id="Hidden8" type="hidden" />
        </td>
        <td id="cell9" onclick="chose9()">
            <input id="Hidden9" type="hidden" />
        </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  </table>
```

This is my function for the winning combination but its not working as well, I tried several methods:

```
 function WinningCombinations(){
    if (document.getElementById("cell1").innerText == "X")
       (document.getElementById("cell2").innerText == "X")
       (document.getElementById("cell3").innerText == "X")
   {
        alert("Congratulations X you won.");
    }
   if (document.getElementById("cell4").innerText == "X")
       (document.getElementById("cell5").innerText == "X")
       (document.getElementById("cell6").innerText == "X")
   {
       alert("Congratulations X you won.");
   }
  }
```

Bottom Line Im trying to Achive the following:

1. I want my click to be on the entire cell not on the hidden button.
2. In the if and else if function `chose1()` is not working so that it gives X or O to the newly clicked cell.
3. I'm Trying to Construct the function `WinningCombinations()` so that it rhymes with my very basic coding.

Your help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Ok so a few tips here rather than a full answer. In terms of asking questions, try and be concise about what you are trying to achieve, although most of your question is examples and you haven't waffled too much, it isn't that clear what you are trying to achieve. This will get you more responses. In terms of your coding, You need to revisit what you need to summarise what you are trying to achieve as it using a new function for every cell isn't very efficient, you need to make them more generic so that they can be re used.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your function is so repetitive. Maybe we can fix it:

```
function chose1() {
  for (var i=1; i<10; i++) {
    if (document.getElementById("Hidden" + i).checked = true) { // whoops
      var cell = document.getElementById('cell' + i);
      if (cell.innerText == "") {
        cell.innerText = nextTurn;
        changeTurn();
      }
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

With fewer lines it's easier to spot that instead of checking if the `cell.checked === true`, the function sets `cell.checked = true`.

You can also inline the changeTurn function:

```
nextTurn = nextTurn === 'X' ? 'O' : 'X';
```

Second of all, in tic-tac-toe there are 8 winning combinations, i think you forgot some of them.

Comment: Thanks for your Prompt response, I put 2 combinations just as examples.